# Approximation by a polynomial with small derivative on a neighbourhood of zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous fonction on an interval $[a,b]$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, does there exists a polynomial $p$ on $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x) - p(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ and $|p'(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ where $|f(x)|< \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: What does it mean that $|f|$ is small? What is the quantifier for $\varepsilon$?

Comment: I hope my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Suppose $(2+b-a) \epsilon < 1/n$.  Then you can take
 $$f(x) = c \frac{x-a}{b-a}$$ where $$ (2+b-a) \epsilon < c < 1/n $$
Suppose polynomial $p$ satisfies your conditions. Since $|f(x)| \le c < 1/n$
everywhere, $|p'(x)| < \epsilon$ everywhere, and $$|p(b) - p(a)| \le \int_a^b p'(x)\; dx < (b-a)\epsilon$$  But we need $$|p(b) - p(a)| > f(b) - f(a) - 2 \epsilon = c - 2 \epsilon > (b-a)\epsilon$$ contradiction!